# Browser compatibility while using anchor tag

Tags: html

I am using `anchor tag` for linking my welcome page to my main page. It is working on chrome but not in `mozilla`.

Code:

```
 <div id="wel1"><h1>WELCOME TO ASSESMENT ENGINE</h1></div>
 <div id="wel2">
     <div id="wel3"><p id="wel4">Instruction:</p><br>
        <p id="lang">Total number of questions : 5.<br><br>
            Time alloted : 3 minutes.<br><br>
            Each question carry 10 mark, no negative marks.</p> 
     </div>
     <div id="wel5">
        <p id="wel4">
           Note:</p><br>
        <p >
          <ul>
            <li><p>Click the 'Submit Test' button given in the bottom of this page to Submit your answers.</p></li>
            <li><p>Test will be submitted automatically if the time expired.</p></li>
            <li><p>Don't refresh the page.</p></li>
          </ul>
        </p>
     </div>
     <a href="as.html"><button id="bu">START THE TEST</buttton></a>  
 </div>
```

In this image START THE TEST button working on chrome perfectly but not on mozilla.

Comment: Why not just style the anchor tag and get rid of the button tag all together?....

Comment: Check in Mozilla console, you will find error like, the button tag can not be nested under anchor tag .. mozilla follow strict rules and does not allow exceptions that are not valid.. That may be the reason behind this.. Alternate Solution is posted in previous comment by @BuddhistBeast :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid close tag `</buttton>`
Try:-

```
<a href="as.html"><button id="bu">START THE TEST</button></a>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdfH5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Although the code works if the end tag spelling error is corrected, it is illogical and forbidden in HTML5 to nest interactive elements: the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) must not have interactive content like a `button` element. A click on such an element could activate the outer element, or the inner element, or both. Although this might not matter in this specific case, it’s still not recommended.

Instead, you can use an image of a button an make it a link:

```
<a href="as.html"><img src="start.png" alt="START THE TEST" border="0"></a>
```

or use a minimal form (submitting a form is different from following a link, but the differences often don’t matter, or could be an improvement):

```
<form action="as.html"><button type="submit">START THE TEST</button></form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Spell mistake in the Closing button tag, Use `</button>` instead `</buttton>`